# numpy version creating issue. python 2.7 already installed

Tags: macos, numpy, matplotlib, ipython, homebrew

Getting few "package missing" errors while installing ipython on High Sierra.

matplotlib 1.3.1 has requirement numpy>=1.5, but you'll have numpy 1.8.0rc1 which is incompatible.

Comment: Numpy is currently at 1.14. matplotlib is at 2.2. Are you sure you don't want to get some new versions?

Comment: I did upgrade matplotlib to 2.2 and when I tried upgrading numpy, it said python 2.7 required, which is already there. Is there any work around this? @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: The information you supply here is not sufficient to know what's happening. Make sure you install to the correct python version, that's all one can say here.

Answer (score 3):

I just met the same problem. It's a issue about numpy preinstall in Python has a version number issue(required >=1.5, but found 1.8.0rc1).

Try running `brew install python2` to upgrade your python which may solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution provided by The Matplotlib development team:

https://matplotlib.org/faq/installing_faq.html#which-python-for-osx