# matplotlib 1.3.1 has requirement numpy>=1.5, but you'll have numpy 1.8.0rc1 which is incompatible

Tags: python, macos, numpy, matplotlib, pyaudioanalysis

I'm executing bellow command in Mac (High Sierra) as a part of getting started with [pyAudioAnalysis](https://github.com/tyiannak/pyAudioAnalysis).

```
pip install numpy matplotlib scipy sklearn hmmlearn simplejson eyed3 pydub
```

I'm getting following error during the installation process. Appreciate your input.

**matplotlib 1.3.1 has requirement numpy>=1.5, but you'll have numpy 1.8.0rc1 which is incompatible.**

Please find more information below,

```
Channas-MacBook-Pro:~ channa$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct  6 2017, 22:29:07) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
[3]+  Stopped                 python
Channas-MacBook-Pro:~ channa$ pip -V
pip 10.0.0b2 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-10.0.0b2-py2.7.egg/pip (python 2.7)
Channas-MacBook-Pro:~ channa$ sudo pip install numpy matplotlib scipy sklearn hmmlearn simplejson eyed3 pydub
The directory '/Users/channa/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/channa/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (1.8.0rc1)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (0.13.0b1)
Collecting sklearn
  Downloading sklearn-0.0.tar.gz
Collecting hmmlearn
  Downloading hmmlearn-0.2.0-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (183kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 184kB 189kB/s 
Collecting simplejson
  Downloading simplejson-3.13.2.tar.gz (79kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 81kB 256kB/s 
Collecting eyed3
  Downloading eyeD3-0.8.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (167kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 174kB 100kB/s 
Collecting pydub
  Downloading pydub-0.21.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from matplotlib) (1.5)
Collecting tornado (from matplotlib)
  Downloading tornado-5.0.1.tar.gz (504kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 512kB 354kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=1.5.6 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from matplotlib) (2.0.1)
Collecting nose (from matplotlib)
  Downloading nose-1.3.7-py2-none-any.whl (154kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 163kB 213kB/s 
Collecting scikit-learn (from sklearn)
  Downloading scikit_learn-0.19.1-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (8.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 8.0MB 259kB/s 
Collecting python-magic (from eyed3)
  Downloading python_magic-0.4.15-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pathlib (from eyed3)
  Downloading pathlib-1.0.1.tar.gz (49kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 54kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: six in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from eyed3) (1.4.1)
Collecting futures (from tornado->matplotlib)
  Downloading futures-3.2.0-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting singledispatch (from tornado->matplotlib)
  Downloading singledispatch-3.4.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting backports_abc>=0.4 (from tornado->matplotlib)
  Downloading backports_abc-0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
matplotlib 1.3.1 has requirement numpy>=1.5, but you'll have numpy 1.8.0rc1 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: scikit-learn, sklearn, hmmlearn, simplejson, python-magic, pathlib, eyed3, pydub, futures, singledispatch, backports-abc, tornado, nose
  Running setup.py install for sklearn ... done
  Running setup.py install for simplejson ... done
  Running setup.py install for pathlib ... done
  Running setup.py install for tornado ... done
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions
```

Comment: Such questions seem to be flooding in recently. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49613437, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49634510, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49640389, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49662022, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49638201

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to solve this with @Jacob's solution with some additional steps. I'll post it here for anyone else facing this.

1. Firstly as Jacob mentioned I downloaded and installed the latest [Python 2.7.14+](https://www.python.org/downloads/).
2. Executed `sudo easy_install pip` to install pip again
3. Executed `sudo pip install numpy`

Answer (score 1):

Download the latest version of Python 2.7 (https://www.python.org/downloads/), matplotlib install should work fine after that.

Also if it's a brand new mac, just make sure that you have command line tools installed

Comment: I just installed the latest python 2.7.1.4
Now I get following,

Channas-MacBook-Pro:~ channa$ pip install numpy matplotlib scipy sklearn hmmlearn simplejson eyed3 pydub
Collecting numpy
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: )