# Matplotlib: Nose, Tornado

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, jupyter

Because I'm trying to install jupyter on my mac, I upgrated my pip. It showed me everything is all right, but then I noticed this:

```
    Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-10.0.0b2-py2.7.egg (10.0.0b2)
     matplotlib 1.3.1 requires nose, which is not installed.
     matplotlib 1.3.1 requires tornado, which is not installed.
     matplotlib 1.3.1 has requirement numpy>=1.5, but you'll have numpy 1.8.0rc1 which is incompatible.
```

What does this mean? Will my matplotlib work normally even if I don't have numphy>=1.5?

I tried fixing it like suggested [matplotlib 1.3.1 has requirement numpy>=1.5, but you'll have numpy 1.8.0rc1 which is incompatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49670554/matplotlib-1-3-1-has-requirement-numpy-1-5-but-youll-have-numpy-1-8-0rc1-whic) but it doesn't work:

```
sudo -H pip install numphy

Password:
Requirement already satisfied: numphy in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (0.0.1)
matplotlib 1.3.1 requires nose, which is not installed.
matplotlib 1.3.1 requires tornado, which is not installed.
matplotlib 1.3.1 has requirement numpy>=1.5, but you'll have numpy 1.8.0rc1 which is incompatible.
```

Comment: Similar questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49670554/matplotlib-1-3-1-has-requirement-numpy-1-5-but-youll-have-numpy-1-8-0rc1-whic

Comment: @MrT Didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's relaxing to see someone has done your job by asking what you exactly needed to. Still, it's a bit cranky to know you are far away from the problems which ppl have faced years ago!

Answer (score 95):

I got the same issue.
You have to install the said dependencies. Which are nose, tornado, and numpy version greater than 1.5
Do the following

```
sudo easy_install nose
sudo easy_install tornado
```

As for the last part regarding numpy version greater than 1.5 you have to get the latest version of python. Refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49670554/matplotlib-1-3-1-has-requirement-numpy-1-5-but-youll-have-numpy-1-8-0rc1-whic)

Comment: I got the same issue when I'm trying to pip install colorama, and this commands solve the issue.

Answer (score 27):

After some searching I found a way to install the packages without checking the current version, for example, for installing *matplotlib*:

```
sudo -H pip install --ignore-installed matplotlib
```

I am not sure if there is a better way, but at lease it let me keep working. I hope it helps

Answer (score 16):

I was having the `nose` and the `tornado` issues on OSX (High Sierra) when I was attempting to install awscli. I got `nose` and `tornado` installed with pip itself:

```
pip install tornado nose --user
```

Afterwards, the awscli install went smoothly

```
pip install awscli --user
```

Comment: `--user` will install to the Python user install directory for your platform, e.g., `/Users/<username>/Library/Python/2.7/bin`. You might want to add it to the PATH environment variable.

Comment: for me it worked fine after install awscli with ```sudo```

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this command if you have pip installed -

```
pip3 install pandas --user
```